# Django Heroku Channels Live Chat Fail

Tags: python, django, heroku, websocket

I've deployed my app on Heroku and everything works fine EXCEPT the live chat (used websockets for this). I'm not sure what is going on. The live chat feature works perfectly fine in development. I have not setup the postgres database or AWS S3 yet for file storage, but that doesn't have much to do with why the chat isn't working I suppose. Here are my files related to heroku and the live chat:
settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
 "default": {
 "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
   }
}
```

Profile:

```
web: gunicorn reddix.wsgi --log-file -
```

There is an error that says I need to use wss (it doesn't say this if I use http) so I already how to fix that issue. The bigger issue is that the live chat does not work on either ws/http or wss/https. It keeps saying:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://myapp-test.herokuapp.com/pathtochat/' failed
Here are my requirements.txt:

```
aioredis==1.3.1
asgi-redis==1.4.3
asgiref==3.4.1
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==21.2.0
autobahn==21.3.1
Automat==20.2.0
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.0
bleach==4.0.0
boto3==1.18.30
botocore==1.21.30
cffi==1.14.6
channels==3.0.4
channels-redis==3.3.0
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==3.4.8
daphne==3.0.2
distlib==0.3.2
Django==3.2.6
django-bleach==0.7.2
django-ckeditor==6.1.0
django-cleanup==5.2.0
django-crispy-forms==1.12.0
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-model-utils==4.1.1
django-notifications-hq==1.6.0
django-storages==1.11.1
djangorestframework==3.12.4
filelock==3.0.12
gunicorn==20.1.0
hiredis==2.0.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.2
incremental==21.3.0
jmespath==0.10.0
jsonfield==3.1.0
msgpack==1.0.2
msgpack-python==0.5.6
packaging==21.0
Pillow==8.3.1
platformdirs==2.2.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-decouple==3.4
pytz==2021.1
redis==2.10.6
s3transfer==0.5.0
service-identity==21.1.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
swapper==1.1.2.post1
Twisted==21.7.0
txaio==21.2.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
urllib3==1.26.6
virtualenv==20.7.2
webencodings==0.5.1
whitenoise==5.3.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

Would truly appreciate any help.